# abrir collapse depois que atualizar array

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, angular, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho um collapse que quando clico nele, vem os dados do array, ai tem um botao que abre o modal, quando eu abro o modal eu clico em 'FINALIZAR', ai quando clico eu envio os dados para a api, e depois atualizo o array, só que quando atualizo o array o collapse fecha e nao abre, ja tentei utilizando $(`#dadosColab-0`).collapse('show') e nao foi.

HTML:

```
 <a href="#dadosColab-{{ i }}" class="btn btn-outline-primary but-href"
                          data-toggle="collapse">{{formatDate(dados.key)}}</a>
    <div id="dadosColab-{{ i }}" class="collapse {{i}}">
             ....
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary button_not_auth" data-backdrop="static" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalExemplo" (click)="notAuth(dados, i)">
        Não aut.
       </button>

     <div class="modal fade" id="modalExemplo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                        aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

    ....
<form [formGroup]="NotAuthBh" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
     <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary 
       button_visu">Finalizar</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary button_not_auth"
        data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
      </div>
</form>
    </div>    
   </div>
```

TS:

```
onSubmit(){
 //aqui envio os dados para api e chamo a function que faz a requisição na api para atualizar os dados.
this.getAllResults() //function q atualiza array
}

getAllResults(){
...
$(`#dadosColab-0`).collapse('show') //chamo p abrir o modal, mas ele nao abre de jeito nenhum
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi assim:

```
 OnSubmit() {
$('#modalExemplo').modal('hide');      
        let dados = this.dados;
        this.dadosColab = this.dadosColab.filter(function (elem, index, array) {
            return array[index] !== dados;
        })
         this.dadosColab;

        setTimeout(function(){ $(`#dadosColab-0`).collapse('show'); }, 0);

}
```